Github Actions Review Approval Conditions
we've just explored a lot through online but no luck so far. We would like to check if this solution will be applicable on our workflow:
- Github Approval window will pop and will be only active for 30 minutes
- If 30 minutes has gone and no approval or denied input receive, the workflow will run something like a rollback task and will exit 1.
- If approve input was sent then the 30 minutes countdown will stop and proceed to next step
- If denied input was sent then the 30 minutes countdown will stop and proceed to next step

